# Dynamically build map at runtime using xml?

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

I have an XML file that defines a map for an object -- it basically tells me to map:

```
A -> _a
B -> _b
C -> SomeFunction(_d)
```

I'd like to parse this at runtime (easy enough) and then somehow initialize an automapper map for this.. I've tried a few times but I can't figure out how to do this.. Is there some overload of ForMember I'm missing? Some other way to do this?

Comment: Can you please post if you found any solution to this? I'd be interested in this as well.

Comment: Afraid not.. never got it to work, I'll probably write something in the future to do it, but nothing's out there that i can find